# How can access the previous value of a merged stream?

Tags: dart, flutter, reactive-programming

I've been struggling with this for couple of hours and can't seem tof ind a solution. I'll appreciate any help.

I building a flutter app trying to follow the BLOC pattern.
I have a widget with two text fields: Country code and PhoneNumber.
I have define a Bloc with two Sink (one for each field) and a Stream with a state. The Stream State is a merge of the two sink such as:

```
factory AuthenticationBloc(AuthenticationRepository authRepository) {
    final onPhoneChanged = PublishSubject<String>();
    final onCountryChanged = PublishSubject<String>();

    //oldState would be the last entry in the stream state.
    final stateChangeFromThePhone = onPhoneChanged.map((newPhone)=>oldState.copyWith(phone:newPhone));
    final stateChangeFromtheCountry = onCountryChanged.map((newCountry)=>oldState.copyWith(country:newCountry));
    final state = Observable.merge[stateChangeFromThePhone, stateChangeFromtheCountry];
}
```

This is pseudo code but the idea is there. My question is how can I get access to the latest event from the state stream represented in the code by oldState?

I could define a variable on which I store this value on each new event in the state stream but looks ugly... :(

Any advice?

Comment: You can't. If you want to, you have to purposefully expose it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Do you have any recommendation on how to implement this kind of pattern. It does not seem to ba like a crazy use case... Most of the exemple have a simple input. Not a combination of several inputs to compute the output state :(

Comment: Considering you're using rx, you could use a `buffer` operator. Such as [`bufferCount`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/bufferCount.html). And make an observable that emit the current value + the previous one together.

Comment: Thanks.Unless I'm missing something, I'm not sure this is doable as it is not the previous version of the phone or country code that I need. but the previous version of the state "When" the phone or the country change. This leave me with no other choice than to expose the previous state by saving it in a variable. Weird that no elegant solution exist for this...

Comment: I don't get what you want. If `merge` doesn't fit your case, maybe `combineLatest` or any other fusion operator will do.